# Storing relational data in Apache Flink as State and querying by a property

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a database with Tables **T1(id, name, age)** and **T2(id, subject)**. 
Flink receives all updates from the database as event stream using something like [debezium](https://debezium.io/). The tables are related to each other and required data can be extracted by **joining** **T1** with **T2** on **id**. Currently the whole state of the database is stored in Flink MapState with **id** as the key. Now the problem is that I need to select the row based on **name** from **T1** without using **id**. It seems like I need an index on **T1(name)** for making it faster. Is there any way I can automatically index it, without having to manually create an index for each table. What is the recommended way for doing this?. I know about [SQL streaming on tables](https://flink.apache.org/news/2017/04/04/dynamic-tables.html), but I require support for updates to the tables. By the way, I use Flink with Scala. Any pointers/suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that you are connecting T1 and T2, and storing some representation (in MapState) of the data from these two streams in keyed state, keyed by id. It sounds like T1 and T2 are evolving over time, and you want to be able to interactively query the join at any time by specifying a name.

One idea would be to broadcast in the name(s) you want to select, and use a KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction to process them. In its processBroadcastElement method you could use ctx.applyToKeyedState to compute the results by extracting data from the MapState records (which would have to be held in this operator). I suspect you will want to use the names as the keys in these MapState records, so that you don't have to iterate over all of the entries in each map to find the items of interest.

You will find a somewhat similar example of this pattern in https://training.data-artisans.com/exercises/ongoingRides.html.